# Solve: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{1^3+3^3+5^3+7^3+...+\left(2n-1\right)^3}{\left(1+3+5+7...+\left(2n-1\right)\right)^2} \right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Solve the following limit
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{1^3+3^3+5^3+7^3+...+\left(2n-1\right)^3}{\left(1+3+5+7+...+\left(2n-1\right)\right)^2} \right)$$

Comment: The l'Hospital rule isn't usefull in this limit! can you calculate the derivative here?

Comment: Its $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ so any one can use L'Hospital rule

Comment: So please show me how we can!!

Comment: @kalpeshmpopat Sami's point is that l'Hopital only applies for _continuous_ functions, those with derivatives that can be calculated - but what you have here is a _discrete_ sum.  There's no meaning to the expression '$\sum_{i=1}^{4.391} (2i-1)^3$'.

Comment: ok sorry for my confusion

Comment: I posted an answer explaining how to cheat and use l'Hôpital anyway.

Comment: As somehow who loves remembering things visually, I believe that it's nice to remember the following picture: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b9/Sum_of_cubes.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use l'Hôpital's rule, but you can use a discrete version known as the [Stolz theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem). Let's try this.

Let $a_n = 1^3 + 3^3 + \ldots + (2n-1)^3$ and $b_n = (1 + 3 + \ldots + (2n-1))^2$.

The discrete derivatives (that is, sequences of differences): $a_{n+1} - a_n = (2n+1)^3$ is trivial; for $b_{n+1} - b_n$, it helps to notice that actually $b_n = n^4$, so (looking at the 4th row on Pascal's triangle), $$b_{n+1} - b_n = (n+1)^4 - n^4 = 4n^3 + 6n^2 + 4n + 1$$

Now, we have 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {a_{n+1}-a_n} {b_{n+1}-b_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {(2n+1)^3} {4n^3+6n^2+4n+1} = \frac {2^3} 4 = 2$$

Therefore, by the [Stolz theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), the wanted limit $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {a_n} {b_n}$ is also $2$.

Answer (score 3):

$$1^3+3^3+\ldots+(2 n-1)^3 = ((2n-1)n)^2 - 2^3 \left (\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right)^2$$

$$1+3 +\ldots+(2 n-1)=n^2$$

Comment: wont that be $((2n+1)n)^2 - 2^3 \left (\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$??? @RonGordon

Comment: @AbhraAbirKundu: no.  Look at the sum in the numerator.  If I were to take your value, I'd get a negative number for that sum.

Comment: Ok It will basically be same...... I mean both are equal

Comment: @AbhraAbirKundu: no it won't; or, I have absolutely no idea what you mean by "it."

Comment: $((2n-1)n)^2 - 2^3 \left (\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right)^2$=$((2n+1)n)^2 - 2^3 \left (\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$

Comment: For the limit, that will work out.  But it is sloppy to just say that they are the same. The sum in the OP's question specifically says something.  The formula you posted is incorrect, even though it provides the same limiting behavior.

Comment: $n^2((2n-1)^2-2(n-1)^2)=n^2(2n^2-1)$ is same as what i have got by expanding my formula .So what's your point?????(You dont really need to expand) You can sum the cubes of i upto 2n and then subtract the cubes of $2i$ upto n  or you can can sum the cubes of i upto 2n-1 and then subtract the cubes of $2(i-1)$ upto n to get the same result.

Comment: (I guess 5 ?'s express exasperation.)  My point is that a sloppy presentation does not teach the subject matter well.  I get that the differences are the same and the subsequent result is correct.  But $((2 n-1) n)^2$ is the correct sum of the first $2 n-1$ cubes, not $((2 n+1)n )^2$.  You may think of this as nitpicking and maybe it is, but it does not help the OP and future people trying to figure out how this is all derived when you write down the wrong sum.  That is my point.

Comment: I really cant see a single mistake in my computation of the sum....... @RonGordon

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\sum_{i=1}^{2n}i^3=(\frac{2n(2n+1)}{2})^2$
and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

$\sum_{i=1}^{2n}i^3=\sum_{i=1}^{n}((2i-1)^3+(2i)^3)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(2i-1)^3+\sum_{i=1}^{n}(2i)^3=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(2i-1)^3+8(\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^2=(\frac{2n(2n+1)}{2})^2$

$\Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{n}(2i-1)^3=(\frac{2n(2n+1)}{2})^2-8(\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^2=(n(2n+1))^2-2(n(n+1))^2=n^2((2n+1)^2-2(n+1)^2)=n^2(2n^2-1)$

Similarly $\Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{n}(2i-1)=\frac{2n(2n+1)}{2}-2\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=n^2$

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{1^3+3^3+5^3+7^3+...+\left(2n-1\right)^3}{\left(1+3+5+7...+\left(2n-1\right)\right)^2} \right)=\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac{n^2(2n^2-1)}{n^4})=2$$

Comment: @RossMillikan The original post was incorrect but has since been edited so that it is now fine.

Comment: I was referring to an earlier version, which the poster has updated.

Comment: Sorry for this confusion. I had made a mistake in observing the terms.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: 
$$1^3+2^3+\dots+n^3 = \bigg(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\bigg)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{1\le r\le n}(2r-1)^3=8\sum_{1\le r\le n} r^3-12\sum_{1\le r\le n}r^2+6\sum_{1\le r\le n}r-\sum_{1\le r\le n}1$$

Now, we can prove $\sum_{1\le r\le n} r^k=O(n^{k+1})$ for integer $k\ge 0$

Alternatively,

$\sum_{1\le r\le n}1=n ;\sum_{1\le r\le n}r=\frac{n(n+1)}2; \sum_{1\le r\le n}r^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$

Now, $\sum_{1\le r\le n}(2r-1)=\frac n2\{2\cdot1+(n-1)\cdot2\}=n^2$

$$\text{So, }\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{1\le r\le n}(2r-1)^3}{(\sum_{1\le r\le n}(2r-1))^2}$$

$$=8\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(\frac{n(n+1)}2\right)^2}{n^4}-12\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{O(n^{2+1})}{n^4}+6\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{O(n^{1+1})}{n^4}-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{O(n^{0+1})}{n^4}$$

$$=2\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac1n\right)^2=2$$